# converting SNMP octet string to float (readable string)

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I'm running a number of SNMP queries to a Hytera dmr repeater. However, the SNMP object definition looks like this:

```
rptVswr OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX  OCTET STRING(SIZE(4))
        MAX-ACCESS read-only
        STATUS  mandatory
        DESCRIPTION
                "The VSWR.
                 It should be changed to float format. "
        -- 1.3.6.1.4.1.40297.1.2.1.2.4
        ::= { rptDataInfo 4 }
```

After running the query, I got an result like this:

```
Name/OID: rptVswr.0; 
Value (OctetString): 0x76 D5 8B 3F
```

Does anyone have an idea how to convert that string into a readable format? 
It should be something like this : `1.15 or 2.15`

Many thanks for your help,

BR - Nils

Answer (score 0):

Here is pretty simple C++ app that decodes hex data and converts it to float:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char ptr[] = {0x76, 0xD5, 0x8B, 0x3F};
    reverse(ptr, ptr + 4);
    float f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(ptr);

    cout << f << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is `2.16559e+33`

Answer (score 0):

My experience with RF devices is that the SNMP replies are either in decimal or hex format and represent power in mW. If you take your get response 0x76 D5 8B 3F, and convert hex to decimal, you get 1,993,706,303 mW. This translates to 1.9937 kW. For VSWR, this is an accurate and acceptable measurement if your forward power is 2+ MW.